# WinError 10057 :error with recieving data

Tags: python, sockets, server, connection, client

I am trying to create a connection between client and server but i cant send messages to it.

> Error : "[WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was
>   disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a
>   datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied"

Also there is no error on the server side because it thinks that it sent the message.
It seems that I can't send any messages from server to the client other functions they all work but not receiving messages from client.

this is the Client function :

```
def receiving(ip, port, serverNumber) :
    while True :
        try :
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            s.bind((ip , port))
            s.listen(1)
            print('waiting ...')
            conn, add = s.accept()
            print('connected')
            string = '' 
            while True :
                print('starting to receive data')
                string += s.recv(2048).decode()
                print(string)
                if 'OVER' in string :
                    break
            while True :
                try :
                    string = string.replace("OVER","")
                    Connections.MessageTranslator(string,serverNumber)
                    print('data has received :', datetime.datetime.now())
                    break
                except Exception as error :
                    print(str(error))
        except Exception as error :
            print(str(error))
```

and this is my Server function :

```
def server_sender() :
    while True :
        while True :
            try :
                port = Connections.SenderPortGetter()
                ip = Connections.ClientIpGetter()
                ip = ip.replace(" ","")
                ip = ip.replace("\n","")
                ip = ip.replace("\t","")
                break
            except Exception as error :
                print(str(error)) 
        while True :
            try :
                Message = Connections.MessageGetter()
                Message = Connections.InfoExtractor(Message, 100)
                ############################
                while True :
                    try :
                        print('here')
                        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
                        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
                        s.connect((ip , port))
                        break
                    except Exception as error :
                        print(str(error))
                ############################
                i = 0
                while i < len(Message) :
                    s.send(str.encode(Message[i]))  
                    i += 1
                while True :
                    try :
                        i = 0
                        string = ''
                        while i < len(Message) :
                            string += Message[i]
                            i += 1
                        print('problem is here')
                        string = string.replace("OVER","")
                        Connections.OldFilesFolderUpdat(string)
                        break
                    except Exception as error :
                        print(error)
                break
            ####
            except Exception as error :
                print('Big fat error :', str(error))
```